# Angular 2/4 - percentpipe - IE

Tags: angular, percentage, angular-pipe

**`{{ 123 | percent }}`** in chrome and firefox displays as  **`12,300%`**

where as it displays as **`12,300 %`** in IE

i.e., an extra space between number and percent in IE

*Is there any setting in the percent pipe to prevent the space in IE please?*

Comment: which IE are you using ? I cannot reproduce the Issue on Edge...

Comment: @Joniras - it is IE11

Comment: You can try with this : *{{ 13 | percent:'2.2-2' }}* but I don't think it would change much

Comment: Angular 5 decided to stop using the Intl API for i18n because of differences between browsers. Upgrade, and you shouldn't have any difference anymore.